# SQL Join using Case Statement on Substrings of Different Length Results in Crossjoin

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to join two tables so that the deepest substring that matches is returned. So if my first table has 'AAA'and 'ABA' and my second table has 'A' and 'AB' then the join should return 'A' and 'AB' respectively. Unfortunately it is returning three rows. I want to do this without using multiple joins and coalesce. This is what I have.

```
With t1 as (
  Select 'AAA' as V from dual
  Union all
  Select 'ABA' as V from dual
)

,t2 as (
  Select 'A' as m from dual
  Union all 
  Select 'AB' as m from dual
)

,r1 as (
  Select
    t1.v
    ,t2.m
  From t1
  Left join t2 on
   t2.m = Case
     When substring(t1.v,1,2) = t2.m
      then substring(t1.v,1,2)
     When substring(t1.v,1,1) = t2.m 
      then substring(t1.v, 1,1)
   End
)

Select * from r1
```

Unfortunately I get duplicates for ABA in my results

| V | M |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | A |
| ABA | A |
| ABA | AB |

I have tried a few flavors of this (flipped t1 and t2 in the on statement and the join order) and none have gotten me to the desired result. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: are you sure that is oracle that you use substring is not oracle function

Comment: A join is only going to consider 1 record on each side of the join, so the fact that another record is also joined is not going to be taken into account. Therefore, you would need to add a further statement to remove the records that you don’t want - I don’t believe you can achieve what you want just by manipulating the join condition

Comment: What does 'deepest' mean? can you tell us the rule about why ABA/A is not a match?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Should `t2.m` be a substring of `t1.a`? For example, if there's no `A` record in `t2` should `AAA` and `AB` match on prefix or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, Use a `LATERAL` join and then use `ORDER BY LENGTH(m) DESC` and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` (or `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`) to get the longest match(es):

```sql
With t1 (v) as (
  Select 'AAA' from dual Union all
  Select 'ABA' from dual
),
t2 (m) as (
  Select 'A'  from dual Union all 
  Select 'AB' from dual
)
SELECT t1.v
     , t2.m
FROM   t1
       LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT m
         FROM   t2
         WHERE  t1.v LIKE t2.m || '%'
         ORDER BY LENGTH(t2.m) DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t2
       ON 1 = 1
```

Which outputs:

| V | M |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | A |
| ABA | AB |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DfK6R4yb)

Comment: This is exactly what was needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just another approach. Sample data is somewhat *poor* so it depends on what you really have and whether my suggestion makes sense at all. Basically, you'd calculate *distance* between two strings, sort results on *similarity* and return the ones that match the most.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     t1
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'AAA' AS V FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'ABA' AS V FROM DUAL),
  7     t2
  8     AS
  9        (SELECT 'A' AS m FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 'AB' AS m FROM DUAL),
```

Query begins here:

```
 12     temp
 13     AS
 14        (SELECT t1.v,
 15                t2.m,
 16                UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (t1.v, t2.m) sim,
 17                ROW_NUMBER ()
 18                   OVER (PARTITION BY t1.v
 19                         ORDER BY UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (t1.v, t2.m) DESC) rn
 20           FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2)
 21  SELECT v, m
 22    FROM temp
 23   WHERE rn = 1;

V   M
--- --
AAA A
ABA AB

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your own query to make it work then this is how you could do it. The reason you're seeing unwanted rows is that the join is evaluated row by row. To solve the issue that you are getting the rows with only a single substr character, rank the results and then only take the highest rank:

```
With t1 as (
  Select 'AAA' as V from dual
  Union all
  Select 'ABA' as V from dual
)

,t2 as (
  Select 'A' as m from dual
  Union all 
  Select 'AB' as m from dual
)

,r1 as (
  Select
    t1.v
   ,t2.m
   ,CASE
     WHEN SUBSTR(t1.v,1,2) = t2.m
      THEN 2
     WHEN SUBSTR(t1.v,1,1) = t2.m 
      THEN 1
   End as rn
  From t1
  left join t2 on
   t2.m = CASE
     WHEN SUBSTR(t1.v,1,2) = t2.m
      THEN SUBSTR(t1.v,1,2)
     WHEN SUBSTR(t1.v,1,1) = t2.m 
      THEN SUBSTR(t1.v, 1,1)
   End
), r2 as 
(Select v, m, rn, rank() over (partition by v order by rn desc) as rnk  from r1)
select v, m from r2 where rnk = 1;

V   M
--- --
AAA A
ABA AB
```